# vscode retain intellisense of dynamically required node.js modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

In order to prevent long, relative paths when requiring node.js modules with the `require` function, at our organization we use a `resolver` module that resolves paths to other modules depending upon given parameters and folder locations. For example, instead of:

```
const User = require('../../../common/models/user.js');
```

We do something like:

```
const resolver = require('../../../resolver.js');
const User = resolver.require('user', 'common/models');
```

This is good to some point, but requiring modules this way makes **visual studio code** to lose track of the required modules, not being able to provide intellisense: no suggestions, no autocomplete, no type hints etc.

Note that this `resolver.require` function generates paths dinamically. VScode is smart enought to provide intellisense for a module `a.js`, in a `c.js` file:

```
const b = require('...path-to-b');
const a = b.requireA(); //const a has intellisense
```

given a `b.js` module that:

```
exports.requireA = function(){return require(path_to_a.js)}
```

However, it loses track of the require module if such `resolver.require` function generates the path from a parameter variable, which is the case.

After a bit of research I haven't found anything that could solve the issue... **maybe there is a way to inform the intellisense engine how to pair our `resolver.require` calls with .js files?**